# Supremum $\sup_{x\in (0,+\infty)}|F(x,t)|=\sup_{x\in (0,+\infty)}\dfrac{e^{-t^2}}{x+|t|}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

> Let :
>   \begin{aligned}F \colon (0,+\infty)\times \mathbb{R} &\longrightarrow \mathbb{R} \\(x,t) &\longmapsto F(x,t)=\dfrac{e^{-t^2}}{x+|t|}.\end{aligned}

- How they do to find  $\displaystyle \sup_{x\in (0,+\infty)}|F(x,t)|$

$$ \fbox{ $\sup_{x\in (0,+\infty)}|F(x,t)|=\sup_{x\in (0,+\infty)}\dfrac{e^{-t^2}}{x+|t|}=\dfrac{e^{-t^2}}{|t|} $} $$

Indeed,

$\forall t\in \mathbb{R}\quad F(.,t)=\dfrac{e^{-t^2}}{x+|t|}$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,t)=\dfrac{-e^{-t^2}}{(x+|t|)^2} $$

I'm stuck here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any fixed $t$, one may see it as a function of a single variable $x$:
$$
f(x)=\dfrac{e^{-t^2}}{x+|t|}, \quad x>0,
$$ giving
$$
f'(x)=-\dfrac{e^{-t^2}}{(x+|t|)^2}<0,
$$ thus $f$ *is decreasing over* $(0,\infty)$, its supremum is obtained as $x \to 0^+$: 
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x \to 0^+}\dfrac{e^{-t^2}}{x+|t|}=\dfrac{e^{-t^2}}{|t|}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The supremum of this value is achieved when the denominator has the infimum value which is achieved for $x=0$.